# Create and push an association at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Word model and a Category model.

Words has_and_belongs_to_many Categories.
Categories has_and_belongs_to_many Words.

Now, I have everything setup and running in the console, for example you can do:

```
Word.create(title: "Testicles")
testicles = Word.first

Category.create(title: "Genitalia")
genitalia = Category.first

testicles.categories << genitalia

testicles.categories
=> "genitalia"
```

Now I can get this up and running using forms in the views too, but only if I have separately created the Category in its own form on a separate page, and same with the Word. Then in the Word show view I can create a form to assign the category to it.

HOWEVER... what I really want to do is to do all this at the same time when I create the Word i.e. on the 'new word' view.

I'm having big problems working out how to do this. I *think* I'm right in saying that I can only have one form and one submit in that view, so I think I somehow have to send everything from that form to, say, the WordsController, and work some magic in there, but exactly what to do here is giving me big headaches. Can anyone help?

I haven't created a User model or setup authentication yet, so there are no obstacles in that respect.

models/word.rb:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

models/category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :words

    validates :title, presence: true
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150529144121) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories_words", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "word_id"
  end

  add_index "categories_words", ["category_id"], name: "index_categories_words_on_category_id"
  add_index "categories_words", ["word_id"], name: "index_categories_words_on_word_id"

  create_table "words", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "words", ["user_id"], name: "index_words_on_user_id"

end
```

After experimenting with various form_tag wizardry (and failing badly), at the moment I'm using this form:

```
<%= form_for(@word) do |f| %>
  <% if @word.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@word.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this word from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @word.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, 'Word' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description, 'Definition' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :categories, 'Category' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :categories %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the view, the form has:

```
#<Category::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f16dd834820>
```

in the 'Category' box, but this can be cleared and your own category inputted. When submitting the form with all the fields filled in, I get a NoMethodError.

Comment: look up `accepts_nested_attributes` --

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to create both a word and a category at the same time, and link them. If the classical solutions (for example using the `nested_form` gem) don't do exactly what you want, you can try this approach.

You really want a custom view/controller for this and do the business in your controller as you suggest. I suggest that instead you used a simple `form_tag` where you can add some fieldsets.

*View*

```
<%= form_tag your_custom_route_path, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |form| %> 
    <%= fields_for :word, @word do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <% end %>

    <%= fields_for :category, @category do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

*routes*

```
post '/yourRoute', to: 'your_controller#your_action_create', as: 'your_custom_route'
```

*Controller featuring some actions*

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  # new
  def your_action_new
    @word = Word.new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # Post
  def your_action_create
    @word = Word.new(word_params)
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @word.save and @category.save
      @word.categories << @category
      @word.save 
    end
  end

  private

  def words_params
    params.require(:word).permit(:title, ...)
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title...)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cyril DD's help, I've expanded on that and created a form and custom controller that will create a new Word with a new Category assigned to it and/or the user can assign existing Categories to that new Word.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "new_word", action: "create_word_and_category", method: "post") do %>

  <% if @word.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@word.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @word.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= fields_for :word, @word do |word_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= word_form.label(:title, "Word:") %><br>
      <%= word_form.text_field(:title, id: "new_word", required: true) %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= word_form.label(:description, "Definition:") %><br>
      <%= word_form.text_area(:description) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <%= fields_for :category, @category do |category_form| %>
    <% if Category.count > 0 %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= category_form.label(:title, "Choose from existing Categories:") %><br>
        <%= category_form.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <h4>AND/OR...</h4>

    <div class="field">
      <%= category_form.label(:title, "Create and Use a New Category:") %><br>
      <%= category_form.text_field(:title) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new_word_controller.rb (it's not completely finished yet, but it 'does what it says on the tin'):

```
class NewWordController < ApplicationController

    def create_word_and_category
        @word = Word.new(word_params)

        if @word.save
            (params["category"])["category_ids"].each do |i|
                next if i.to_i == 0
                @word.categories << Category.find(i.to_i) unless @word.categories.include?(Category.find(i.to_i))
            end

            if category_params.include?(:title) && ((params["category"])["title"]) != ""
                @word.categories << Category.new(title: (params["category"])["title"])
            end
        end

        if @word.save
            redirect_to words_path, notice: 'Word was successfully created.'
        else
            redirect_to new_word_path, notice: 'A valid word was not submitted.'
        end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # def set_word
    #   @word = Word.find(params[:id])
    # end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def word_params
      params.require(:word).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
    end

    def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:title, :category_ids, :category_id)
    end

end
```

In my routes.rb:

```
post 'create_word_and_category' => 'new_word#create_word_and_category'
```

I'm having going to place that controller code into the old words_controller, because I don't see a need to have it in a separate controller like this. If anyone has any thoughts/critique, great. And if anyone can help me write an rspec controller test for this controller code, even better! I'm having trouble with that.